# Sql 2005 get latest entry from a group of data

Tags: sql, t-sql

### Problem:

I have a set of data that keeps track of history of communication between clients. So each client has their own activity history (notes, emails..etc). I need to get the latest entry from each client's activity history, where each row is the latest entry from a client's activity. So every row is unique on **client id** and we can call each activity, **"description"**.

Each activity has a date, and some other jargon like subject, body.

### Activity Table

```
activityid  |  clientid  |  subject  |  body  |  datemodified
```

Thanks!

Comment: Exact table structures would be useful

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'd like to know the database (incl. version), and see an example of expected output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not giving us much to go off of but here is a shot in the dark:

```
SELECT ClientId, body, MAX(DateModified)
FROM Activity
GROUP BY ClientId, body
```

Comment: Thanks! That was a good shot in the dark. Sorry for my vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ClientId, Body, MAX(DateModified)
  FROM Activity
 GROUP
    BY ClientId, Body;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+

```
;with cte AS
(
SELECT activityid, clientid, subject, body, datemodified,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY datemodified DESC) AS RN
FROM Activity
)
SELECT activityid, clientid, subject, body, datemodified
 FROM cte
 WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what You are asking for is the last entered line for each client You can use a sentence like this:

```
SELECT activityid, clientid, subject, body, datemodified
FROM Activity as ac
WHERE datemodified=(
    SELECT max(datemodified)
    FROM Activity
    WHERE cleintid=ac.clientid
)
```

Comment: This actually narrows it down to 1 entry, the one with the latest date. I'd like 1 entry per client, where the entry is the latest modified entry.